# Literature Reference UV Transmission Quartz Glass

Tags: optics, resource-recommendations

Out method strongly depends on the UV transmission of Quartz glass, and we know it is very high. Now, reviewer #2 asked for a literature reference for the paper.

Does anyone have a suggestion for a citable reference, preferrably not behind a paywall as I am doomed to home office?

Comment: If from, e.g., Schott, their product literature should have some information. Unclear if you actually have the glass (so you got it from somebody who should have data), or if you have a design that requires some transmission (and then you look at various suppliers that give transmission curves). Check Edmund optics, Heraeus, Schott, various laser optic suppliers, etc.

Comment: I am sorry if I sound very critic, but what kind of science are you doing that "we know it is very high"...what are you claiming the cut-off is? And do you have quartz or fused silica? Quartz is crystalline and birefringent while silica is a glass and has different properties, so "quartz glass" does not make any sense. Both quartz and fused silica are very studied materials. Check www.refractiveindex.info . Quartz starts absorbing strongly around 180nm. Your institution does not provide a VPN for paper access?

Comment: Hi @JoséAndrade, thanks for the link, but for fused silica, I can only find the refractive index and the reflectance (Malitson, 1965) listed there, but no data on transmission. By they way, Refractiveindex.info lists "quartz glass" as a synonym for fused silica.

Comment: check korth krystalle GmbH, they have transmission graphs down to 100 nm or so. But probably not citable. 

(I work in Germany and in German, it is called "Quartzglas", which makes some German colleagues sometimes call it quartz glass, colloquially in speech, however, in any scientific setting, if in English, only silica or fused silica is used within my community)